# Simple matching pairs app, comparing two TextViews

Tags: android, textview, match

I'm trying to make a simple matched pairs app. The app starts with all TextViews having "#" as a text. When I press a text field, it changes to a letter which was stored for that field.

Anyway, I want to open two fields (I mean to change their strings) and compare them. If they are equal, they remain "opened" with new letters (e.g. both are "A"). In the case with equal letters, everything works fine, but I have difficulties when the letters differ.

If they are not equal, I want to make them to show themselves with new text for one second and after that to go to the previous sign (i.e. "#"). When I press the first field, it changes its text but when I go for the second field and if their stored letters are not equal, the second field doesn't change the text and the text from the first field goes back to the previous sign.

What do I need to do to show fields with new text for a short period of time if their Strings are not equal?

This is how my table looks:

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    int counterForPressedFields= 0;
    int textViewForComparationCounter = 0;
    TextView firstTextViewForComparation;
    TextView secondTextViewForComparation;
    int[] nonPressedFields= {1, 1, 1, 1};
    int pressedField = 2;
    int tag = 0;


    public void show(View view) throws InterruptedException {

        textView = (TextView) view;

        tag = Integer.parseInt(textView.getTag().toString());

        if (nonPressedFields[tag] == 1) {

            nonPressedFields[tag] = pressedField;

            if (counterForPressedFields< 2) {
                textViewForComparationCounter += 1;
                counterForPressedFields+= 1;

                switch (tag) {

                    case 0:
                        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.front1);
                        textView.setText("A");
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.front2);
                        textView.setText("B");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.front3);
                        textView.setText("A");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.front4);
                        textView.setText("B");
                        break;
                }

                if (textViewForComparationCounter == 1) {
                    firstTextViewForComparation = (TextView) view;
                    firstTextViewForComparation = textView;

                } else if (textViewForComparationCounter == 2) {
                    secondTextViewForComparation= (TextView) view;
                    secondTextViewForComparation= textView;
                }
            }

            if(counterForPressedFields == 2){
                if(firstTextViewForComparation.getText().toString().equals(secondTextViewForComparation.getText().toString())){

                    counterForPressedFields= 0;
                    textViewForComparationCounter = 0;
                }else{

                    firstTextViewForComparation.setText("#");
                    secondTextViewForComparation.setText("#");
                    nonPressedFields[Integer.parseInt(firstTextViewForComparation.getTag().toString())] = 1;
                    nonPressedFields[Integer.parseInt(secondTextViewForComparation.getTag().toString())] = 1;
                    counterForPressedFields= 0;
                    textViewForComparationCounter = 0;
                }
            }

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a handler. You can update your textViews back to "#" with its postDelayed method.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //update your textViews here
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(runnable, millisecondsOfDelay);
```

Hope it helps!